# Converting WPF local resource to application resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a local resource in XAML and I want it to be used by other parts of the code. How can I make it "global" (i.e. an application-wide resource)? Here is my local resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary >
   <local:BoolToLightConvertor x:Key="LightConverter" / >
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I put this in the App.xaml?

Comment: Instead of declaring a converter locally or globally a good practise is to derive the converter from markup extension and use it wherever you want. see this article for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55715/WPF-Where-to-put-value-converters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file (e.g. SharedResources.xaml) as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace.Here;assembly=Your.Assembly.Here">
    < local:BoolToLightConvertor x:Key="LightConverter" / >
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your App.xaml add the following lines:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

You can now use this converter from within the XAML

(The `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>` is a workaround to stop a WPF bug ignoring your resource dictionary and was recommended by another question here on SO. The link unfortunately eludes me now though)

Answer (score 1):

Application Resources
In addition to defining resources at the level of the element or Window, you can define
resources that are accessible by all objects in a particular application. You can create an application
resource by opening the App.xaml file (for C# projects) or the Application.xaml file
(for Visual Basic projects) and adding the resource to the Application.Resources collection, as
shown here:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="appBrush" Color="LightConverter" />
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: you added here your built in resouse ( solidcolorbrush) , instead i want to add my own class , which is BoolToLightConvertor , how to do that ?